# WPF drag and drop only working when dropping on the items in the listview

Tags: wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop

So I have a listview in which I set up drag and drop, but for some reason it only lets me drop inside the actual items in the listview, rather than on any portion of the controltemplate that I overrode. How do I make it so that I can also do drag and drop over the textblock containing the title for the column?

```
     <ListView
        Margin="0,4,0,0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        x:Name="NameListView"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path = AddedItems}"
        SelectionChanged="NameListView_SelectionChanged"
        AllowDrop="True"
        SelectionMode="Extended"
        VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
        >

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                  <Border 
                    Name="Border"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    >
                    <ContentPresenter 
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                      />
                  </Border>
                  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                      <Setter TargetName="Border"
                              Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}"
                              />
                    </Trigger>
                  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>


            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDoubleClick" Handler="NameListView_PreviewMouseDoubleClick"/>
          </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <!-- Until NET 4.0 Keygesture's cannot bind to a command, so the inputbindings must be set using static commands or with code behind-->



        <ListView.Template>
          <!--Template Defining the layout of this treeview-->
          <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid 
              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
              >
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition 
                  Height="{Binding GraphHeight, Source={x:Static DaedalusGraphViewer:SettingsManager.AppSettings},
                          Converter={StaticResource GridLengthConverter}}"
                  />
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="18" />
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <Border
                Grid.ZIndex="1"                    
                Grid.Row="0"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                >
                <Grid>
                  <TextBlock 
                    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="Signal Names"
                    />
                </Grid>
              </Border>
              <Canvas>
                <Line 
                  Grid.ZIndex="2"
                  x:Name="SelectedItemUnderline"
                  Stroke="Black"
                  StrokeThickness="3"
                  Visibility="Collapsed"
                  />
              </Canvas>
              <ScrollViewer 
                Grid.ZIndex="1"                    
                x:Name="SignalNameScrollViewer" 
                Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                CanContentScroll="False"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                >
                <ItemsPresenter />
              </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </ListView.Template>


      </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a first chance exception being handled inside the drag operation, so when I fixed that code, it allowed me to drop anywhere in the listview. Basically, if an exception is thrown in the drag handlers, the mouse cursor will display not available to drop and fail drop